# Php SoapClient with WS-Security cannot authenticate and SOAPUI can

Tags: php, soap-client, ws-security, digest

I connect to a web service with SOAPUI, I have correct credentials. The server requires PasswordDigest, with *nonce* etc. When I call service with SOAPUI, *it works*.

When I use *WSSoapClient* php class from https://gist.github.com/silasrm/a57a1e3af165cb43644b712192625a3b

or a bit developed version from https://gist.github.com/Turin86/5569152, 
I am getting:

- *An error was discovered processing the  header*
- *The security token could not be authenticated or authorized*

respectively.

The MS manual https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms977327.aspx explains:

*The nonce is 16 bytes long and is passed along as a base64 encoded value.* 
The examples there suggest that *nonce* is sent base64'd.

In the first version of *WSSoapClient* *nonce* is a random number (does not have 16 bytes surely), is pack()'d and base64()'d.

In the second version *nonce* is a random number only sha1'd. I do not think this may be correct, since "original" content of *nonce* must be concatenated with time and password, then base64(pack(sha1())).

Correct header from SOAPUI and failing header from php soap clients look the same, except for calculated values:

```
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-01010101010101010101010101">
    <wsse:Username>XXXXXXXX</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">jbpPIWuudp4l/l+ZqoR4iAN08lU=</wsse:Password>
    <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">yXy5R5w6I3km75hha8mYqg==</wsse:Nonce>
    <wsu:Created>2018-08-27T09:07:54.101Z</wsu:Created>
```

To keep it short: do you have a working version of some ws-security *SoapClient* in php?